# What does "dibbura" mean in Targum Jonathan Exodus 33:11 "the voice of the Word (dibbura) was heard"

Tags: targumin

Is this "Word", the Memra of God, if yes, why a different word is used instead of *Memra*?

Targum Jonathan [Exodus 33:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Targum_Jonathan_on_Exodus.33.11?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

> And the Lord spake with Moses word for word,- the voice of the Word (dibbura) was heard, but the Majesty of the Presence was not seen,- in the way that a man converseth with his companion.

Answer (score 1):

The word used in Targum Yonatan, דבורא, is translated as *prophetic revelation*  according to Jastrow.

So following the word ממלל in his Targum are words explaining the meaning of the phrase פנים אל-פנים from the Hebrew text.

That Yonatan ben Uziel is explaining generally there are different levels of prophecy and this Hebrew phrase is referring to a specific level of prophecy.